# How do I make PowerShell read a file as single lines when it thinks there are multiple lines?

Tags: powershell

I have an input file with the following lines:

```
1000095710|SavRx
1000124602|Mason’s Pharmacy
1001130436|Regence
1001314900|HealthE Systems
1001322929|IT management
```

Which I created with the the line:

```
$line = $numValueYouSee + "|" + $fd.Replace("Client", "") #Client used to say ClientNameOfClientYouSeeNowAsSavRx
```

When I read the new output file with PowerShell using `$FileText = gc "Path\To\File.txt"`, it is reading the lines as the following:

```
1000095710
|SavRx

1000124602
|Mason’s Pharmacy

1001130436
|Regence

1001314900
|HealthE Systems

1001322929
|IT management
```

I can verify the lines of the file by just clicking arrow keys, but in Notepad++ I can see extra CR-LFs. How can I fix this ridiculous output to the correct output?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Maybe you have some weird encoding on the file?

Comment: please post all your code, including the code that creates the file. Currently there is not enough information for us to replicate your problem

Comment: Pipe the output to `$FileText|Format-Hex` to see if there are other (control) characters embedded

Comment: kind of cool, format-hex returns the same things you'd see in a hex editor minus the position of the cursor....nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your data fields have trailing CR characters. Demonstration:

```
PS C:\Temp> $s = "1000095710`r|SavRx`r`r`n1000124602`r|Mason's Pharmacy`r`r`n"
PS C:\Temp> [IO.File]::WriteAllText('c:\temp\out.txt', $s)
PS C:\Temp> Get-Content .\out.txt
1000095710
|SavRx

1000124602
|Mason's Pharmacy
```

You can remove them by trimming your fields before creating the output.

```
$line = $numValueYouSee.Trim() + "|" + $fd.Replace("Client", "").Trim()
```

Comment: You were right about creating the field itself. I actually pulled this data from an ie com object to get specific webpage text, and it seems to have hidden crs. Thank you-the trim works when making a new file(I removed all crlfs, and just redid each line with a trim to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue either.  Maybe you have to save your file again from notepad. Maybe there is hidden formatting in the text like a hidden "`n"

You could try this:

```
$FileText = Import-Csv Path\To\File.txt -Header Number,Type -Delimiter "|" -Encoding Default
```

Comment: I modified  your line to $filetxt = import-csv $file -delimiter "|" and it gave me each element, with what i'm guessing ... representing it's separator. This is perfect, because the elements are really what I needed so thank you!

Comment: I would add also the -Encoding part, to make sure you have the correct encoding: